# Remove duplicate parenthesis from expression

Tags: c#, string

`((f1=2)AND(f2=3)) -> ((f1=2)AND(f2=3))`     no change

`((f1=2)AND((f2=3))) -> ((f1=2)AND(f2=3))`

`(((f1=2)AND(f2=3))) -> ((f1=2)AND(f2=3))`

I have the above expressions and I want to delete duplicate parenthesis from the string. I  don't know the logic that is necessary to do this in C#.

Comment: anyone can help me to what will be logic or algo will required to achieve this task?

Comment: I assume you want to trim extraneous parens from the inside as well, correct? Example: `(f1=2)AND((f2=3)` -> `(f1=2)AND(f2=3)`

Comment: what is the difference between 2nd and 3rd string in example?

Comment: second sample has duplicate parenthesis after AND

Comment: third has overall or complete expression out parenthesis.. (Sorry for bad english)

Comment: You need to define what "duplicate perenthesis" means, and translate that into code. Because from what I can tell all 3 outputs have duplicate/redundant parenthesis.

Comment: @retailcoder ((X)) - this `is and only` duplicate. We need each ((X)) translate to (X)

Comment: its simple duplicate mean   ((f1=2)) so definitely outer parenthesis is useless.

Comment: Are "AND" and "=" operators the only ones you are considering?  Are you only considering one level, or can things be nested?  Sounds like a good candidate for a Lexical analyzer to break it down into tokens and then you can build it back up any way you like.  I have used lex and flex in c++ projects, I am not too sure which is the best for c#, perhaps Lucene.Net?

Comment: In this example: `((f1=2)AND(f2=3))`, I would then expect it to return `(f1=2)AND(f2=3)`. Is that not accurate?

Comment: this is also accurate

Comment: How is `((bool)) and ((bool))` not starting and ending with one such *duplicate* parenthesis? I think you could simply `s.Replace("((").Replace("))")` and recurse until `((` can't be found in the string anymore.

Comment: @retailcoder consider `(f1=2 AND(f2=3))` removing the `))` would result in `(f1=2 AND(f2=3` which is not a valid expression.

Comment: Right. What if you only removed "))" if "((" was also found occurring before "))" in the string?

Comment: `((f1=2 AND (f3=4)) AND(f2=3))`

Answer (score 2):

My first idea was too complex and didn't work. This one simplier and I hope will work. We just check if there's outer parentheses covering current pair, i.e. when we found `(...)` we check if there's open parenthesis before `'('` and closing one after `')'`. Also we need to remove them when `s="(.....)"`, i.e. when we found outermost parentheses which starts at 0 and close at the end.

```
private string RemoveDoubleParenthesis(string initialString)
{
    char[] s = new char[initialString.Length];
    char toRemove = '$';
    Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        s[i] = initialString[i];
        if (s[i] == '(')
            stack.Push(i);
        else if (s[i] == ')')
        {
            int start = stack.Pop();
            if ((start == 0 && i == (s.Length - 1)) 
             || (s[start-1] == '(' && s[i+1] == ')'))
            {
                s[start] = s[i] = toRemove;
            }
        }
    }

    return new string((from c in s where c != toRemove select c).ToArray());
}
```

As you see, I assume that expression doesn't have errors (missing parantheses).

**UPD** Thanks, @retailcoder. And sorry for messing with answer versions :)

```
var results = string.Join("\n", new string[] 
    { 
        "((f1=2)AND(f2=3))", 
        "((f1=2)AND((f2=3)))", 
        "(((f1=2)AND(f2=3)))", 
        "(f1=2 AND(f2=3))", 
        "((f1=2 AND (f3=4)) AND(f2=3))" 
    }
    .Select(s => string.Format("{0} -> " + RemoveDoubleParenthesis(s), s)));

MessageBox.Show(results);
```

[image: no problem, you're welcome!]

Comment: I got that first version was wrong and changed it

Comment: Strings are immutable, `s.Replace(toRemove.ToString(), "");` doesn't change the value of `s`... *immutable* also means the indexer for `string.this[int]` is read-only and can't be assigned like this - your code doesn't compile as is ;)

Comment: oh, yeah, forgot about that. UPD. how about that?

Comment: Just missing `.ToArray()` at the end of your LINQ statement (and the surrounding parenthesis), otherwise you're passing `IEnumerable<char>` to the `String` constructor, which no overloads accept - try `return new string((from c in s where c != toRemove select c).ToArray());`

Comment: It's okay, I realized after pasting the screenshot that I had messed something up. I need to read up on those chained assignments! I rolled it back.

Comment: @retailcoder thanks. I accidentally overwrote your edit than did wrong rollback and confused at all.